# Moving a Docs collection to a user's Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a collection resource ID from Doclist API.

Now I need to make this collection appear in the user's Drive.

Q1: can we use both the Doclist and the Drive API in one app to do this?

Q2: is it just a question of adding the Drive root parent? If not, what's the incantation?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the Documents List API and the Drive API in the same application, they both operate on the same resources and use the same identifiers. It is recommended that you only use the newer Drive API whenever possible.

I'm not sure I understand your second question. If that collection is in the user's Docslist, then it is by definition in the user's Drive, there is no distinction between the two entities.

If instead you want the collection to appear in someone else's Drive account, then you have to share the resource with the other user, as explained at https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-sharing

Comment: OK, let me clarify: if I share a folder X from user Y to user Z, user Z will not see it in their Drive folder, must find it in "Share with me", and can select Organize and get a popup which states "Item is not in your Drive".  Sounds like "Drive" is just the root folder?  So adding an item to folder:root will "add it to Drive" - does anything else need to happen?